# Apply sortDescriptor to NSFetchRequest after grouping

Tags: swift, core-data, indexing, nsfetchrequest, nssortdescriptor

I am building a Showroom that has 45000+ catalogs each represented as `Literature` in CoreData.

To optimise search - instead of searching over `Literature`, I've added another entity - `LiteratureSearchIndex` in CoreData, that has `searchvalue` (either title word/keyword/tag etc. that represents part of the Literature), `score` (to weight the results) and `literatureid`.

When the user types something in the search or filters - I do a fetchRequest on the LiteratureSearchIndex, group the results and sort them on the total score.

```
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "LiteratureSearchIndex")
        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "LiteratureSearchIndex", in: moc)

        let sumDescription = NSExpressionDescription()
        sumDescription.name = "totalScore"
        sumDescription.expression = NSExpression(forFunction: "sum:", arguments: [NSExpression(forKeyPath: "score")])
        sumDescription.expressionResultType = .integer64AttributeType

        if let literatureid = entityDescription?.attributesByName["literatureid"] {
            request.propertiesToGroupBy = [literatureid]
            request.propertiesToFetch = [literatureid, sumDescription]
            request.havingPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%@ >= %@", NSExpression(forVariable: "totalScore"), NSNumber(value: minScore))
        }

        request.predicate = ... 
        request.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
        request.fetchBatchSize = 50
```

I'm currently sorting the results after the moc.fetch() like this:

```
                results.sort(by: { (a: [String: Any], b: [String: Any]) -> Bool in
                    if let aTotalScore = a["totalScore"] as? Int, let bTotalScore = b["totalScore"] as? Int {
                        return aTotalScore > bTotalScore
                    } else {
                        return true
                    }
                })
```

Is there a better/faster way to sort the results (similar to applying `havingPredicate` over the array of dictionaries)?